# Reverse sorting a list not working in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.7 and something interesting is happening when sorting and I cannot understand why. Maybe someone can help?

```
numlist = [4,8,2,6]
print(sorted(numlist))
print(sorted(numlist[::-1]))
print(sorted(numlist,reverse=True))
```

Output is this:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
[8, 6, 4, 2]
```

I have two questions.

1) Why is the first reverse not actually reversing?

2) Why is the second reverse, which is equivalent, actually working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reversing a thing and then sorting it into ascending order is completely different from sorting it into descending order.

Comment: What have you expected the output to be?

Comment: Sorry, I failed to understand how it was passing the argument, not obvious to me. Not trying to come off as a smart ass, just a misunderstanding of the computation on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sorted(numlist[::-1])`, the `[::-1]` slice simply reverses the list before you pass the reversed list to `sorted`, which sorts it in the default order. And with `sorted(numlist, reverse=True)`, you're actually telling `sorted` to sort in the reversed order since you pass to it the `reverse=True` argument.

Comment: Ok, this makes much more sense. Thank you for explaining that in detail. Really helped me understand!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to understand.

```
print(sorted(numlist)) => print(sorted([4,8,2,6]))
print(sorted(numlist[::-1])) => print(sorted([6,2,8,4]))
print(sorted(numlist, reverse=True)) => print(sorted([4,8,2,6], reverse=True)) => print(sorted([4,8,2,6])[::-1])
```

sort `[4,8,2,6]` has nothing different than sort `[6,2,8,4]`

Answer (score 1):

`print(sorted(numlist[::-1]))` is only reversing your *input* list before it's passed to `sorted`. So, the input to `sorted` is `[6,2,8,4]` instead of `[4,8,2,6]`. `sorted` does not care what the input is; to sort in a descending order, `reverse` arg *must* be passed

Answer (score 0):

It should be `print(sorted(numlist)[::-1])`, you have placed slicing wrong